# Pass an array of images displaying in a UIImage to another different view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I come from JavaScript/HTML5 and I am beginning with Objective-C.

I am creating a basic application using AVFramework where the user selects different types of frames (an Array in form of png images) to be displayed in their final picture.

The app has 3 view controllers. One for shooting the picture, 2nd the one with an array of images(frames) to be displayed and the 3rd one with the final preview.

What is the best approach for passing the tapped image to the final view controller after the picture is taken?

My code that loads with frames in the frame view controller is below:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
 TemplateViewCell *cell = (TemplateViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

TemplateViewCell *frameImageViewCell = (TemplateViewCell *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

frameImageViewCell.frameImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:

[frameImages[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo-frame-2.png"]];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo-frame-selected.png"]];


return cell;
}
```

I want the user to be able to tap on any of the images, move back to the 1st controller, snap the picture and then show the final picture in the last preview.

Comment: Search "pass data to another controller" on this site. There are hundreds of questions and answers on this topic.

Comment: I know but I don't want to pass the data right away. I want to go to another view controller first and then show in the 3rd controller. I did not find a similar answer...

Comment: See my answer below. The tapped image is passed via a property.

Comment: I did that. I created a Controller just for testing at it worked but since I am using AVFramework when I try to do the same with the preview controller (last controller) it overwrites the picture.
Should I write a new class for handling this or should I use NSUserDefaults? What would be the best approach?

Comment: I think you’ll have to post some more code to get a satisfactory answer. Not sure why AVFramework would matter. Passing a property between controller shouldn’t depend on the framework you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Haven’t had much time to look at every thing, but my first thought is to alloc/init the new view controller. Then have a property in that view controller of type UIImage for instance that you set after creating the view controller. You would set the property to your selected image.